# @Html.CheckBoxFor onchange actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I make the code below an on change actionlink? So when I check the checkbox it will trigger an actionlink!

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(c => OutOfBank.Available)
```

Comment: What's your goal? You simply want to imitate a button click with the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an Ajax request when Checkbox changed, which triggers the action each time you check or uncheck the checkbox.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(c => OutOfBank.Available)

<script>
  $(function () {
     $('#Available').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/example/@OutOfBank.Available',
            cache: false,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) { alert('success'); },
            error: function () { alert('error'); }
          });
      });
  });
 </script>
```